# Error unexpected T_VARIABLE PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I cant seem to find why i get the unexpected T_variable error. Im trying to use a class to call my Database. 
The error is on row 18

```
 $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1");
```

And this is my entire class.

Any clues ?

```
 class Users{
        private $link; 
        public function __construct(){
        $this->link = new Connection();
        $this->link = $this->link->dbConnect();
    }

   $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1");  
   $query->$this->link->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    header("Content-type: text/xml");

      while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {  

            $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
            $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
            $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
            $newnode->setAttribute("adress", $row['adress']);
            $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
            $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
            $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
      }
       echo $dom->saveXML();
}
```

line 18 and 19 is

```
$query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1");  
$query->$this->link->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: How we find The line  18?

Comment: plz give us line 17, 18 and 19

Comment: You can't have code inside a class, without it being part of one of the class's functions. Wrap it inside a function and call it from outside the class instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either:

- forgot to close you Users class after the constructor
- forgot to include your code into a class method

Ex:

```
class Users{
    private $link; 
    public function __construct(){
      $this->link = new Connection();
      $this->link = $this->link->dbConnect();
    }
}
```

Or:

```
class Users{
    private $link; 
    public function __construct(){
    $this->link = new Connection();
    $this->link = $this->link->dbConnect();
}

  public function someMethod() {
    $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1");  
    $query->$this->link->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    header("Content-type: text/xml");

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {  

        $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
        $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
        $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("adress", $row['adress']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
    }
    echo $dom->saveXML();
  }
}
```

Comment: Ic I actually did not know that i needed to have it in a function while in class.
Will try, and report back to u :)

Comment: @matheiu Imbert.
So I putted everything like you said and tried to call it like this.
$users = new Users();
$user_info = $users->fetch_Area();

But now i get the error 
 class Users could not be converted to string

Comment: @Dymond That's an entirely different question! And without the code and error message I can't help you. I suggest you check your code, and post a new question if you can't make it work.

Comment: you right, i check this as accept since it got me moving.. thanks